# In Wordpress get category ID within a blog roll

Tags: wordpress

I'm not a fan of the default blog roll for a theme that I'm using, so I'm deconstructing it, so far I was able to pull into the blog roll template:

```
Author: get_the_author_link()
Date with formatting: the_time('F jS, Y');
```

What I'm having trouble with is pulling in the categor(eis) for each post. I've tried:

```
get_the_category(); // with or witout the get_the_ID()
```

But All I get back the array object. I then tried traversing to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Again, this is not an individual post, but a blog roll.

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Not sure what your actual problem is.

Comment: I want to have the blog roll show: Author Name, Date, Post title (with link), and category.

Comment: OK. Check out my answer. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `get_the_category_list()`.

This function takes three parameters - separator, parents and post id (in that order).

So, you'll want to do something like this:

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list(', ', '', get_the_ID()); ?>
```

This will create a an unordered (`ul`) list with commas in between the category names. You will most likely need to use some CSS to make the `li` items float or set them to inline block. Something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="catlink">Cat 1</a>, </li>
   <li><a href="catlink">Cat 2</a>, </li>
   <li><a href="catlink">Cat 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

You can also use `get_the_term_list()`. This has a little more flexibility in the final output of the category terms.

`get_the_term_list()` accepts five parameters: post id, taxonomy, before, separator, after.

For your use you would do this:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'category', '<span>', ', ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

This will output something like this:

```
<span><a href="cat1">Cat 1</a>, <a href="cat2">Cat 2</a>, <a href="cat3">Cat 3</a></span>
```

You can change the wrapper (`<span>`), I just used that as an example.

Here is documentation on both functions from the Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Comment: Right on! Glad I could help.